Is it possible to make a progress bar with any shape (icons or images)?
I was working on a web page containing a timer which shows how many days, hours etc... are left once the final date has been specified (in my case this timer shows how long I have to wait before I meet my gf).
I've decided to add an heart shaped progress bar based on the time left, but the problem is the slider goes outside the boundary of my SVG image and I really don't know how to solve this.
This is the HTML code:
<body>
    <main>
        <section id="content-page-container">
            <section id="counter-container">
                <div class="data-display">
                    <h3 class="data" id="days">00</h3>
                    <p class="data-text">Giorni</p>
                </div>
                <div class="data-display">
                    <h3 class="data" id="hours">00</h3>
                    <p class="data-text">Ore</p>
                </div>
                <div class="data-display">
                    <h3 class="data" id="minutes">00</h3>
                    <p class="data-text">Minuti</p>
                </div>
                <div class="data-display">
                    <h3 class="data" id="seconds">00</h3>
                    <p class="data-text">Secondi</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div>
                <div class="progress-bar-slider" id="slider">
                    <img src="src/images/heart-svgrepo-com.svg" class="heart">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>

and this is the CSS one:
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
        main{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #content-page-container{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        #counter-container{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .data-display{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 1rem;
            width: 6rem;
        }
        .data{
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            font-size: 3rem;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .data-text{
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            font-size: 2rem;
        }

        /*================= Progress bar =================*/
        .progress-bar-container{
            width: 30rem;
            height: 3rem;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        .progress-bar-slider{
            background-color: red;
            height: 100%;
            width: 20%;
        }
        .heart{
            width: 10rem;
        }
        /*================================================*/

        @media (max-width: 576px){
            .data-display{
                width: 4rem;
                margin: 0.75rem;
            }
            .data{
                font-size: 2.5rem;
            }
            .data-text{
                font-size: 1.45rem;
            }
            .progress-bar-container{
                width: 20rem;
                height: 2rem;
            }
        }

This is the final result:

I tried searching everywhere and also asked to ChatGPT but nothing...

You need to clip the progress bar to the svg.

@Paulie_D But how?

clip-path - check it out

@Paulie_D I'm really having an hard time doing this because i can't reference the svg. Can you show me how would you implement this?
